# How to find the path of subclasses, between a class and an instance of one of its subclasess?

Tags: php, inheritance

I am working on a PHP project in which a lot of classes are high leveled in the class tree, i.e. they have a lot of parent classes.

At some level, consider there is a class `Food`, which has quite a lot of subclasses and sub-subclasses etc. I want to implement a method `getFoodClasses()` in class `Food` that gives me an array of all subclasses that lead to the current instance, i.e. classes in the tree between class `Food` and the current instance, including the latter. The `Food` class itself and all its superclasses should not be included in the result.

Example: if a subclass of `Food` would be `Vegetable`, which has a subclass `Fruit`, which then has a subclass `Banana`, then the result of on `(Banana) $b->getFoodClasses()`, needs to result in `array('Vegetable', 'Fruit', 'Banana').

So,

```
class Food extends SomeBaseClass
{
  public function getFoodClasses()
  {
    /* Here goes the magic! */
  }

}

class Vegetable extends Food      {}
class Fruit     extends Vegetable {}
class Banana    extends Fruit     {}

$b = new Banana;
print_r($b->getFoodClasses());
```

Which results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Vegetable
    [1] => Fruit
    [2] => Banana
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with this function.

```
/**
 * Calculates the widget path between this class and the current instance.
 * @return array An array with all subclasses in the path between this class and the current instance.
 */
public function getFoodClasses()
{
   $reflClass = new ReflectionClass(get_class($this));
   $classes   = array();

   while ($reflClass->getName() != __CLASS__)
   {
      $classes[] = $reflClass->getName();
      $reflClass = $reflClass->getParentClass();
   }

   return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using reflection, you can still use some simple php functions to achieve this.

```
class Food
{
  public function getFoodClasses()
  {
    $class = get_class($this);

    $classes = array($class);
    while (($parentClass = get_parent_class($class)) && $parentClass != "Food")
    {
      array_unshift($classes, $parentClass); // Push onto the beginning because your example shows parents before children.
      $class = $parentClass;
    }
    return $classes;
  }
}
```

Comment: Very nice to see that the PHP builtins can achieve this as well. I won't use the solution at the moment as I like using the SPL, but looking at your code, it seems to do exactly what it should do. One should ideally do a benchmark on both implementations, to see which one is favourable when it comes to performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference; this code actually works (starting from Banana, going to Food).

```
<?php
class Food
{
  public function getFoodClasses()
  {

  }
}

class Vegetable extends Food      {}
class Fruit     extends Vegetable {}
class Banana    extends Fruit     {}

$banana = new Banana;

$class = new ReflectionClass( get_class( $banana ) );

$parents = array( );

while( $parent = $class->getParentClass( ) ) {
    $parents[] = $parent->getName( );
    $class = $parent;
}

var_dump( $parents );
```

Comment: Well, that doesn't stop at the current class either. :) (I should have mentioned that more precise in my example, see my update in which Food has a parent class as well.) And, in your example, the `Food` entry is also included. That shouldn't happen.

Comment: A bit unclear. What I mean with my comment above, is that I do not want Food's superclasses to appear in the result.